# Highlight custom token inside quoted string in ace editor

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I've lost so much time trying to figure this out, read multiple articles, but without any luck.

What I'm trying to do is highlight a custom token inside a quoted string.

Ex:

```
    Dim code As String = "SELECT G123C432 FROM table WHERE G321C234 = G87C1"
```

I've imported a vb.net language grammar to ace, and it's ok, but now I want to highlight `G123C432`, `G321C234` and `G87C1`.

The vb.net grammar file has this token for quoted string:

```
    "#quotedString": [{
      token: "string.quoted.double.vbnet",
      regex: /"(?:[^"]|"")*"/
    }]
```

And I've added this rule:

```
    "#mlkField": [{
      token: "mlkfield.vbnet",
      regex: /G[\d]+C[\d]+/
    }]
```

I've tried the regex `G[\d]+C[\d]+` but it doesn't work when found inside a `String`.

Example of an expected final result:
[editor snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FhVv.png)

Comment: Is this a highlighting conflict? I.e. your regex works, but the whole string is being highlighted due to the conflicting rule? (And if so would your custom rule "take priority" by placing it higher in the list? Is that the behaviour you expect?)

Comment: @TomLord, changing the order doesn't work either. Not sure if it's a conflict problem. Did you see the screenshot of the expected result?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't provide a screenshot of the *actual* result. (Does the quoted string get highlighted? Does a custom token that's not inside a string get highlighted?)

Comment: Sorry @TomLord, the quoted string is hightlighted, but the custom token doesn't even when not inside a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a separate state for the string

```
"#quotedString": [{
    token: "string",
    regex: /"/,
    push: [{
        token: "mlkfield.vbnet",
        regex: /G[\d]+C[\d]+/
    }, {
        token: "string",
        regex: /"/,
        next: "pop"
    }, {
        defaultToken: "string"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks @a-user, works perfectly. I had tried following the guide at [link](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter) but with no success.